# malware Js code removal from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, malware, malware-detection

i keep getting this malware code in my wordpress , even if i do a clean install of my wordpress  a few hours later its back again :/ i cant remove it... i keep finding the code below in many of mine .js files ... any one could give me advice on how to clean this ? tks

[[/*ef9eb9c4a1ef1138e92465976f9f.....f1138e92465976f9ff8b0*/]]

i installed wordfence sucuri ativirus and bulletproof but still getting problem

Comment: What else do you have on your webspace? Some script has a leak. Change your passwords (ftp etc.)

Comment: i did that.. i have a few paid plugins ... and a few free ones ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have completely removed wordpress and reinstalled from a fresh copy including all plugins, then the issue is on the server. Is the site hosted with other sites? One of those could be the issue. Did you change your hosting account AND ftp passwords or just ftp? Did you review your access logs and look for unusual POST activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install gotmls plugin for resolving your issue 
scan it and fix the affected files

It will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

If anyone sees this on 2023:
In order to remove completely any malware or backdoor code do the following (In Wordpress only - although some of the recommendations applied for any website):

1. Disconnect the hosting from the Domain (to avoid attacks while fixing it
2. Remove all Wordpress files except the WP_CONTENT folder
3. Update Wordpress manually thru FTP article [here](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/updating-wordpress/)
4. Use sucuri sitecheck to see more details about the [malware](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/)
5. Clean the Database. Search for the malware. Sometimes hackers do SQL Injections.
6. Update Database, cPanel, Website passwords stronger than before.
7. Disable editing the WP-config file [(only on wordpress)](https://serverguy.com/wordpress/disable-file-editing-in-wordpress-admin-area)  to avoid force brutte attacks over
8. Connect the hosting to the domain again

*make sure to have properly set permissions over the folders and files (755, 644, and 600 on wp-config.php file

Previous steps also applied when the malware comes back again and again.